# Normal distribution and algebra problem

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Bags of cement are labeled $25 \operatorname{kg}$. The bags are filled by machine and the actual weights are normally distributed with mean 26.0 kg and standard deviation $0.50 \operatorname{kg}$. It is decided to purchase a more accurate machine for filling the bags. The new mean is $25.5$ and the standard deviation is $.255$. The cost of the new machine is $\$5000$. Cement sells for $\$0.80$ per $\operatorname{kg}$. Compared to the cost of operating with a $26 \operatorname{kg}$ mean, how many bags must be filled in order to recover the cost of the new equipment?

I'm unsure of why the answer is $12,500  --- 5000 / (0.5 \cdot 0.8 )$

Why isn't it $20.4$ because of $5000 / (25.5 \cdot 0.8)$? I know that the question wants to compare the new mean with the old, but I'm not quite clear on what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that the old machine is underselling each bag by an average of $\mu _1 - 25 = 1 {\rm kg}$, and the new machine is underselling each bag by an average of $\mu _2 - 25 = 0.5{\rm kg}$.

Hence the average savings per bag by switching to the new machine is $1 {\rm kg} - 0.5 {\rm kg} = 0.5 {\rm kg}$.

Since the cement sells for \$0.80 a kilo, this is an average savings of $0.5 {\rm kg} \cdot 0.8 {\rm \$/kg} = {\rm \$ 0.40}$ per bag.

Hence to recoup the full investment, the company needs to sell $$n = \frac{\rm \$5,000}{\rm \$ 0.40} = {\rm 12,500\; bags}$$ to recoup the investment.

Answer (score 0):

On average the weight of a bag is only 0,5 kg (=25.5-25) over 25 kg with the new maschine-instead of 1 kg (=26-25) . The equation is $\Delta e=p \cdot \Delta w\cdot q$.

$\Delta e$= difference of earnings=$5,000

$\Delta w$=difference of the weights per bag=1 kg/bag-0.5 kg/bag=0.5 kg/bag

q=amount of bags

p=price of a bag of cement=$0.8/kg

You have to solve the equation for q.

Thus on average you have sell 12,500 bags to recover the costs. In this calculation the concept of the *expected value* has been used.

**Remark**:

It is not sure, that you recover the costs. With the sample size of 12,500 bags, there is a possibility, that you do not recover the costs, because the weights of the bags are random variables. It is also possible, that your additional earnings are higher than 
$5,000.